# android - share session between two webviews?

Tags: android, session, webview, cookiemanager

first of all, can someone please explain how does `CookieManager.getInstance()` work? I don't really get how I can get the session from webview? Lets say if I have this

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(WebviewPage.this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
```

Do I get the session from the class named `WebviewPage`? but what if I named my actual `WebView` to `webview`, how can `cookieManager` get the session of `webview`? not even talk about if I had two `WebView`, `webview1` and `webview2`. How do I know which session that was stored in `cookieManager`??

My main question is...I have two activities and one webview in each activity. How can I get the session from Activity A and pass it to the webview in Activity B?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't need to set cookie for webview2.
webview2 will automatically use the cookies from webview1.

Comment: how does that work? do all the webviews (in the same activity and different) are sharing the same session?

Comment: does that mean no matter where I call `CookieManager.getInstance();`, it will always get the same session?

Comment: Yes, when you call CookieManager.getInstance(); in the same app, it will always get the same session.

Comment: yes. All webviews in the same app will share the same session

Comment: i've tried it, but it doesn't seem to be that way...cookie & session are not shared.

Answer (score 0):

[CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) seems to be a singleton, so when you call getInstance() you always get the same instance. So if webview 1 set some cookies on the CookieManager, or if you set it your self using [set Cookie](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), all other webviews should get the same cookies as well.