# Android - Sessions in two webview

Tags: php, android, session, webview

i have in my app two activities, and in each activity i have a web view.
if i created a session in my php code in the first webview, can i read this session in the 2nd webview??

and what is the cookiemanager used for? is it for reading the sessions created over the server (by php) or there is a session created over the app?

the same question is asked here: 
[android - share session between two webviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228701/android-share-session-between-two-webviews)
but i didn't get the exact answer!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is only ONE instance of the [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) per application, so by default, if you log into a website in one activity and then go to another activity without logging out, you should be logged in if going to that website in the second activity. Actually, I've found it basically impossible to not be logged in the second activity due due to there only being one `CookieManager` instance, without clearing the cookies or disabling cookies...

Cookies in the `CookieManager` basically handle themselves, although you can get and remove cookies from the database for a particular website.